# Vistecture tool не может найти конфиг через Docker: stat no such file or directory

Tags: golang, docker, микросервисы

Имеется [тула](https://github.com/AOEpeople/vistecture), которая позволяет визуализировать зависимости микросервисов. 
Но, к моему сожалению, никакой информации, кроме загадачно описаной документации в *readme*, нету.

Итак, пытаюсь запустить локально [пример](https://github.com/AOEpeople/vistecture/tree/master/example) из гитхаба. В начале я скачал образ [vistecture tool](https://hub.docker.com/r/aoepeople/vistecture/) в докере.

`docker pull aoepeople/vistecture`

Затем, следуя общей формуле (которая описана в readme, опять же), я прописал следующую команду:

```
docker run -v C:\Users\SlandShow\Github\vistecture-master\example\demoproject -p 8080:8080 aoepeople/vistecture vistecture --config=demoproject serve
```

Cама по себе общая формула тут прописана в документации с оглядкой на *Linux*, а на моей машине сейчас как-бы Винда стоит:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/workspace -p 8080:8080 aoepeople/vistecture vistecture --config=/workspace serve
```

Соответственно, `$(pwd):/workspace` в моём случае я поменял на абсолютный путь к конфигу vistecture.

Ну и получаю ошибку в итоге -
`2019/03/02 19:16:08 stat demoproject: no such file or directory`.

Хотя, опять же, следуя из [примера](https://github.com/AOEpeople/vistecture/blob/master/example/generate-documentation.sh), workspace - это папка с yml конфигом.

Помимо всего прочего, эта тула написана на Go. Может есть способ запустить через Go? Я запутался.

*Как мне решить эту проблему?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, *URL* монтировки был неправильным.

Было:

```
C:\Users\SlandShow\Github\vistecture-master\example
```

Должно быть:

```
/c/Users/SlandShow/Github/vistecture-master/example
```

Во-вторых, общая команда ожидает совсем другой синтаксис (`$(pwd):/workspace`). Это означает, что команда монтировки выглядит так:

```
docker run -v /c/Users/SlandShow/Github/vistecture-master/example:/demoproject
```

Так как была скачена папка с проектом, внутри которого был нужный конфиг, появилась вложенность.

```
docker run -v /c/Users/SlandShow/Github/vistecture-master/example:/demoproject -p 8080:8080 aoepeople/vistecture ls
bin
demoproject
dev
etc
home
lib
media
mnt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

И теперь можно посмотреть, что внутри **demoproject** есть ещё один **demoproject**.

```
docker run -v /c/Users/SlandShow/Github/vistecture-master/example:/demoproject -p 8080:8080 --rm aoepeople/vistecture ls /demoproject
Readme.md
build-with-docker.sh
demoproject
generate-documentation.sh
templates
```

А уже внутри `demoproject/demoproject` находится нужный файл с описанием вистектуры...

```
docker run -v /c/Users/SlandShow/Github/vistecture-master/example:/demoproject -p 8080:8080 --rm aoepeople/vistecture ls /demoproject/demoproject
external-services
project.yml
service-group-1
service-group-2
```

Таким образом, нужная локация папки вложена. Кроме всего вышесказанного, в документации неправильно описано то, как глотает файл с описанием `--config`. Ему нужно явно указать полный путь до файла, а не папку, внутри которой содержится оный.

**Конечный результат:**

```
 docker run -v /c/Users/SlandShow/Github/vistecture-master/example:/demoproject -p 8080:8080 --rm aoepeople/vistecture vistecture --config=/demoproject/demoproject/project.yml serve
```

*И ещё желательно перед запуском очистить контейнеры, иначе оно странно работает.*

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

В конце открываем **http://localhost:8080/** и наслаждаемся результатом.

P.S: убедитесь, что докер настроен на шаринг диска. Помимо всего прочего, если вы используете *Cisco AnyConnect*, то фаервол может [ругаться](https://blog.olandese.nl/2017/05/03/solve-docker-for-windows-error-a-firewall-is-blocking-file-sharing-between-windows-and-the-containers/).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]